# Websocketのコネクションが2つになるとブラウザがEOFを送信する。

Tags: go, nginx, websocket

Websocketを使うWebサイトを作成しています。

そのサイトではNginxのupstreamを使ってgoで書かれたサーバにリバースプロキシしています。そのサイトのあるページでWebsocketを使用しているのですが、1つのサーバに2つ以上のコネクションを生成しようとすると、2つ目のコネクションの接続時点で1つ目のコネクションにブラウザからEOFが送られてしまいます。

ローカルでNginxを使わない場合はちゃんと動いているので、問題はNginxにあると考えました。

設定ファイルは以下のようになっています。

**nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server_tokens off;
}

stream{
  upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:50000 weight=5 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
  }
  server {
    listen 443;
    proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
    proxy_timeout 3s;
    proxy_pass backend;
  }
}
```

なぜこのような挙動になってしまうのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

proxy_timeoutが3sになっているのが原因でした。その為3秒でWebsocketのコネクションがきれていました。

これを増やしたところ、コネクションが切れなくなりました。